# Why does my F8 key in Visual Studio keep getting changed?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

On both my work and my home PC I keep getting the following error in Visual Studio 2008 when I hit **F8** to step through results of a search.

I can fix it by resetting my keyboard settings in **Options**, but a few weeks later it will just happen again. Does anyone else experience this and/or know how to stop it changing itself back every so often?

[F8 screenshot http://imgbag.com/joshz/stackoverflow/f8.png](http://imgbag.com/joshz/stackoverflow/f8.png)

Comment: When working on a foreign language project, I kept getting my keyboards switched into cantonese.  Eventually I tracked down a hidden key sequence that was triggering the language change.  I suspect you're in a similar position.

Comment: No it's not the Windows language change thing - I'm aware of that and that's a different (but removable) headache!